# String pattern matching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing some self learning about Patern Matching in Javascript.
I got a simple input text field in a HTML web page,
and I have done some Javascript to capture the string and check if there
are any strange characters other than numbers and characters in the string.
But I am not sure if it is correct.
Only numbers, characters or a mixture of numbers and characters are allowed.

```
var pattern = /^[a-z]+|[A-Z]+|[0-9]+$/;
```

And I have another question about Pattern Matching in Javascript,
what does the percentage symbol mean in Pattern matching.
For example:

var pattern = `'/[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/';`

Comment: "Pattern Matching" is a called Regular Expressions or Regex.  The Regex tag should help you connect with the right people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put multiple character ranges inside a `[]` class.

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
//or 
var pattern = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i // <- using "case insensitive" modifier
```

Percentage symbol means percentage symbol will be matched, it has no special meaning inside a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

`%` in that JavaScript regex doesn't have any special meaning 0 - it's just one more matching character.